# UDP Client/Server Calulator with GUI

Tags: java

[UDP Client/Server Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bXmc.png)

I am having hard times completing the given above. I successfully created the interface but my main issues are sending the numbers and the operation from the client class to the server and then sending the final answer back to the client. Can someone please give me an advice what should I do next.

//Client.Java

```
import java.swing.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;



public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket ();
    
    //Connect to server
    InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");  //12.0.0.1
    int portNumber = 9876;
    
            //Calculator Frame
             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
             frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 200);
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             frame.setTitle("Calculator Assignment" );
             frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
             frame.setVisible(true);
             //Label
             JLabel label = new JLabel("");
             label.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 20);
             label.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 16));
             label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
             label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
             frame.getContentPane().add(label);
             
            
             //First Number Label
             JLabel label1 = new JLabel("");
             label1.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 20);
             label1.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 13));
             label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
             label1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
             frame.getContentPane().add(label1);
             label1.setText("First Number");         
             //Text Field
             JTextField textfield1= new JTextField("");
             textfield1.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 14));
             textfield1.setBounds(140, 20, 150, 20);
             frame.getContentPane().add(textfield1);
             
             
             //Second Number Label
             JLabel label2 = new JLabel("");
             label2.setBounds(20, 40, 200, 20);
             label2.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 13));
             label2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
             label2.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
             frame.getContentPane().add(label2);
             label2.setText("Second Number");
             //Text Field
             JTextField textfield2= new JTextField("");
             textfield2.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 14));
             textfield2.setBounds(140, 40, 150, 20);
             frame.getContentPane().add(textfield2);
             
             //"Answer" Label
             JLabel label3 = new JLabel("");
             label3.setBounds(20, 70, 200, 20);
             label3.setFont(new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 13));
             label3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
             label3.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
             frame.getContentPane().add(label3);

             label3.setText("Answer: ");
             
             //Buttons
             JButton button1 = new JButton("+");
             button1.setBounds(20, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button1);        
                     
             JButton button2 = new JButton("-");
             button2.setBounds(85, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button2);                        
             
             JButton button3 = new JButton("×");
             button3.setBounds(150, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button3);        
                                 
             JButton button4 = new JButton("÷");
             button4.setBounds(215, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button4);        
                                 
             JButton button5 = new JButton("Max");
             button5.setBounds(280, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button5);                        
                 
             JButton button6 = new JButton("Min");
             button6.setBounds(345, 120, 60, 23);
             frame.getContentPane().add(button6);        
            
            
            //Buttons Actions
             button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label3.setText( "Answer: "+ textfield1.getText() + " + " + textfield2.getText() + " = "  + receivedAnswer );
                  }
                 });    
             
             button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label3.setText( "Answer: "+ textfield1.getText() + " - " + textfield2.getText() + " = " + receivedAnswer );
                     }
                 });
             
             button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                     label3.setText( "Answer: "+ textfield1.getText() + " x " + textfield2.getText() + " = " + receivedAnswer);
                     }
                 });
             
             button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label3.setText( "Answer: "+ textfield1.getText() + " ÷ " + textfield2.getText() + " = " + receivedAnswer);                        
                     }
                 });
             
             button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label3.setText("Answer: Maximum is: " + receivedAnswer);
                  }
                 });
             
             button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    label3.setText("Answer: Minimum is: " + receivedAnswer);
                     }
                 });        
             
             
    
        
        //Send First Number
        String sendingFirst = textfield1.getText();
        byte[] SendingFirst = new byte[1024];
        SendingFirst = sendingFirst.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendingPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(SendingFirst, SendingFirst.length, ipAddress, portNumber);
        clientSocket.send(sendingPacket1);
        
        
        //Send Second Number
        String sendingSecond = textfield2.getText();
        byte[] SendingSecond = new byte[1024];
        SendingSecond = sendingSecond.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendingPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(SendingSecond, SendingSecond.length, ipAddress, portNumber);
        clientSocket.send(sendingPacket2); 
        
        
        //Receive reply from server
        byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
        clientSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
        String receivedAnswer = new String(receivedPacket.getData());
        System.out.println(receivedAnswer);
     
        
        clientSocket.close();
        
        
}

}
```

//Server.Java

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;


public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        
        //creating a UDP socket with a port number
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);
        
        while (true) {
            
            //Create empty datagrams
            byte[] receivedData = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket receivedPacket1 = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
            DatagramPacket receivedPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(receivedData, receivedData.length);
            
            //receive from the network through the socket and fill in the empty datagrams
            serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket1);
            serverSocket.receive(receivedPacket2);
            
            //extract data and print it 
            String receivedFirst = new String(receivedPacket1.getData());
            System.out.println(receivedFirst);
            String receivedSecond = new String(receivedPacket1.getData());
            System.out.println(receivedSecond);
            
            
            //Arithmetic Computation and finding Min/Max
            float first = Integer.parseInt(receivedFirst);
            float second = Integer.parseInt(receivedSecond);
            float add, subtract, multiply, divide, maximum, minimum;
            
            add = first + second;
            subtract = first - second;
            multiply = first * second;
            divide = (float) first / second;
            
            if (first > second) {
                maximum = first;
                minimum = second;
            }
            
            else if(second > first) {
                    maximum = second;
                    minimum = first;
                }
            
            else {
                maximum = first;
                minimum = first;
            }
        
            
          //reply to the client that sent the message
            InetAddress ipAddress = receivedPacket1.getAddress();               
            int portNumber = receivedPacket1.getPort();             
            String sendingSentence = "Hello from Server";               
            byte[] SendingData = new byte[1024];                
            SendingData = sendingSentence.getBytes();               
            DatagramPacket sendingPacket = new DatagramPacket(SendingData, SendingData.length, ipAddress, portNumber);  
            serverSocket.send(sendingPacket);   
        
            
            
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
    
    catch (Exception ex) {
        
    }
    
}

}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what problem you're having.

Comment: and the stack trace or the error/problem you are facing.

Comment: According to my understanding of your question, it has nothing to do with [Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info). You want to know how to send data to a server, using UDP, and how to receive an answer. I think you should start by writing a program where you send a hard-coded string from the client to the server and have the server return a string. If you have trouble getting that program to work, then ask here. By the way, I think you should send a string that contains both numbers and the operation, for example, _5+7_ and have the server parse that string.